# Display a table inside an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

*I'm on Oracle DB 12c and using SQL Developer.*

How can I display every rows of a table inside a procedure, if all arguments are "null".

I'm guessing that my IF is correct and I might have seen two or three posts where they used cursors but I'm not very familiar with the utilization of those.

I would like it to basically be a **SELECT * FROM Salle** but with a condition.

Am I on the right track here ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Foo1 (noSalle in varchar2, Cat in varchar2, Nb in number)
IS
 cursor SYS_REFCURSOR; -- Not sure at all about that

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salle : ' || noSalle || 'Cat : ' || Cat);
  IF (noSalle = null AND Cat = null AND Nb = null) THEN
    OPEN cursor FOR 
      SELECT * from Salle;     

  -- Some sort of FOR row IN cursor LOOP ?
  -- Display ALL rows of "Salle"

  END IF;

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Erreur Oracle : '||sqlcode||' ; Message Oracle : '||sqlerrm);
END;
```

Comment: This link contains an example of how to define a cursor, fetch the cursor and display the results. We can solve the problem for you but since it is elementary would recommend that you solve it on your own. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm

Comment: you can't per-say display thing in oracle procedure the way you do in Sql Server. It is really about creating output. And in Oracle it is strict. You need to return  cursor from stored procedure and then do something with it to display data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `SYS_REFCURSOR` is used to hold tabular data usually used when you want to return such data from a function.
- `Null` comparison is incorrect. Use `colname is null` instead.

If you just want to print all the rows using `dbms_output.put_line` or something similar, you can do this

```
for row in (select * from salle) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(row.col1||' '||row.col2);
end loop;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted and thanks for the explanation of the SYS_REFCURSOR. I didn't think you could simply put the querry after the in.